# Javascript/jQuery - Update list display based upon values of array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an `ul` like so:

```
<ul>
<li>foo</li>
<li>bar</li>
<li>baz</li>
...
</ul>
```

Now I have an array being returned via AJAX which contains various values. I'd like to alter the CSS and append data to each of the `li`s where the value within exists within the array.

Sometimes values are repeated, e.g.

```
<li>foo</li>
<li>bar</li>
<li>foo</li>
```

In such cases all matching `li`s should be altered.

I've managed to make this work for a fixed value, but I'd like to run this as a function for each element in the array:

```
$("ul li:contains('foo')").each(function(){
    $(this).append(" found foo");
});
```

Sorry if I'm using the wrong terminology, it's been a while since I did anything Web/JavaScript related.

Comment: Is the array just a bunch of string values? ie `['foo', 'bar', 'foobar']`

Comment: Are you trying to do this? https://jsfiddle.net/z2srtu43/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provied that `a` is your array of values you got via AJAX, you can loop through them and update the elements as follows:

```
var a = ['foo', 'bar'];
a.forEach(function(entry) {
    $("ul li:contains('"+entry+"')").each(function(){
        $(this).append(" found "+entry);
    });
});
```

Full [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/efrotfb2/1/).